# Simple Cube - Three JS

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I've been trying to achieve a simple rotating 3D cube via the Three.js library for WebGL.

I can't seem to identify any faults in my code when compared to the masses of tutorials out there, however all I see is a black screen with no geometry.

```js
//Define window size
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;

//smoothened edges for the renderer defined
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
//renderer size
renderer.setSize(width,height);
//renderer is appended to the html document
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var scene = new THREE.Scene;

//Add Cube - width, height, depth
var cubeGeom = new THREE.CubeGeometry(100,100,100);
var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0x1ec876});
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeom,cubeMaterial);

//Rotate cube 45 degrees
cube.rotation.y=Math.PI*45/180;

//Add cube to scene
scene.add(cube);

//Add Camera - FOV, Ratio, Close, Far
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45,width/height,0.1,10000);

//Position camera
camera.position.y = 160;

//Higher the z value, the closer to the camera/user
camera.position.z = 400;

//Camera pointed towards cube
camera.lookAt(cube.position);

//Add camera to scene
scene.add(camera);

//Define skyBox

var skyBoxGeom = new THREE.CubeGeometry(10000, 10000, 10000);
var skyBoxMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x000000, side: THREE.BackSide });
var skyBox = new THREE.Mesh(skyBoxGeom,skyBoxMaterial);

scene.add(skyBox);

//Point Light
var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
pointLight.position.set(0,300,200);
scene.add(pointLight);

//Render scene
function render() {
  render.render(scene,camera);

  var clock = new THREE.Clock;

  //rotate cube clockwise - subtract time passed from rotation
  cube.rotation.y -=clock.getDelta();

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

//Call render function
render();
```

```css
canvas {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/threejs/r76/three.min.js"></script>
```

p.s. I am linking to Three.js via the CDN found on Google Developer links found here: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/

Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tiny typo in your JS code at line 55:

```
render.render(scene,camera);
```

should be:

```
renderer.render(scene,camera);
```

Next time I highly recommend opening up your browser's console, the error was logged the already, so fixing the bug was very straightforward.

---

Besides of that, your code works just fine. The cube **rotates**, although it's very slow. You may want to adjust line 60 to make it rotate faster (eg. by multiplying the value by 100).

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback mdziekon!